# Row Spaces - Prove $\mathrm{Row}\ A = \mathrm{Row}\ A^T A$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

The question is:

> Prove that the following statement is true.
>
> For any rectangular $m\times n$ matrix A, $(\mathrm{Nul}( A ))^\perp = \mathrm{Row} (A^T A)$

Now, my understanding of the Row space is that it is simply $\mathrm{Col}\ A^T$ (since it is just the Span of all linear combinations of row vectors of A.) I also know that $(\mathrm{Row}\ A)^\perp = \mathrm{Nul}\ A$. Since we can take a double orthogonal complement, we can interchange it: $((\mathrm{Row}\ A)^\perp)^\perp = (\mathrm{Nul}\ A)^\perp \implies \mathrm{Row}\ A = (\mathrm{Nul}\ A)^\perp$.

Hence, the actual proof is now simplified to proving that $\mathrm{Row}\ A = \mathrm{Row}\ A^TA$.

Here is my (incomplete) proof for the above:

Let the matrix A be $m \times n$, consisting of entries of the form of vectors: $A = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}\vec{v_1} & \vec{v_2} & \cdots & \vec{v_n}\end{array}\right]_{m\times n}$, where $\vec{v_i} \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

Now, we take the transpose of A: $A^T = \left[\begin{array}{c}\vec{v_1}^T \cr \vec{v_2}^T \cr\vdots \cr\vec{v_n}^T\end{array}\right]_{n\times m}$

Multiplying the two:
$$A^TA = \left[\begin{array}{c}\vec{v_1}^T \cr \vec{v_2}^T \cr\vdots \cr\vec{v_n}^T\end{array}\right]_{n\times m}\left[\begin{array}{cccc}\vec{v_1} & \vec{v_2} & \cdots & \vec{v_n}\end{array}\right]_{m\times n}$$

Since matrix multiplication is row-column, we simply multiply the transposes and the vectors:

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc} \vec{v_1}^T\vec{v_1} & \vec{v_1}^T\vec{v_2} & \cdots & \vec{v_1}^T\vec{v_n} \cr \vec{v_2}^T\vec{v_1} & \vec{v_2}^T\vec{v_2} & \cdots & \vec{v_2}^T\vec{v_n}\cr 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots\cr \vec{v_n}^T\vec{v_1} & \vec{v_n}^T\vec{v_2} & \cdots & \vec{v_n}^T\vec{v_n}\end{array}\right]$$

By definition, this is dot product:

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc} \vec{v_1}\cdot\vec{v_1} & \vec{v_1}\cdot\vec{v_2} & \cdots & \vec{v_1}\cdot\vec{v_n} \cr \vec{v_2}\cdot\vec{v_1} & \vec{v_2}\cdot\vec{v_2} & \cdots & \vec{v_2}\cdot\vec{v_n}\cr 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots\cr \vec{v_n}\cdot\vec{v_1} & \vec{v_n}\cdot\vec{v_2} & \cdots & \vec{v_n}\cdot\vec{v_n}\end{array}\right]$$

However, this result fails on giving me any insight. How do I proceed with this proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier: Show that $N(A)=N(A^\top A)$, where $N$ is the nullspace.

(1) $N(A)\subset N(BA)$ for any matrix $B$.

(2) $N(A^\top A)\subset N(A)$: If $(A^\top A)x=0$, then $0=x\cdot A^\top (Ax) = Ax\cdot Ax$, so $Ax=0$.

Comment: As a side note, is $Row\ A = Row\ A^TA$ incorrect then?

Comment: No, it’s correct. Just take orthogonal complements. But the easiest proof requires knowing they have the same dimension (one is easily a subspace of the other, but not vice versa), and for this we need the nullity-rank theorem and this equality.